# Deserialization a dependency with overload method with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, overloading

I have a class that is from amazon called DynamodbEvent, which in its methods has an overload of setEventName. I'm doing this to get the instance from a map:

```
mapper.convertValue(input, DynamodbEvent.class);
```

Where mapper is an instance of ObjectMapper. The problem is that is crashing when it founds the overload of the method. I searched and everywhere says that I have to use the annotation @JsonIgnore, but I can't edit this class, and I think that creating a new one just to add that it might not be the solution.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: if you just want to ignore the setter, you can  try `https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations`

Comment: I've already seen that link, but I couldn't understand well how to implement it. I understand that I have to create another class to specify that, or something like that. Could you explain me that a little bit?